# Executable doesn't run as administrator and dependency walker doesn't show any dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, dll

I am running an .exe file in Windows 10 which I built it myself using Visual Studio 2015 using x64 and debug configuration. However after I run it under administrator setting nothing happens. No error! I was suggested to use "Dependency Walker" however it doesn't show me me any missing dll or related dll or lib when I run depends.exe file and open renderdocui.exe file unlike many other tutorials I see from Dependency Walker. Please suggest solutions.

**Code is from https://bitbucket.org/visinf/projects-2016-playing-for-data 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Also here's are information from pestudio executable:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I was suggested to open the command prompt with admin right and run the executable, here's what happened(nothing basically):

```
C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\x64\Debug>renderdocui.exe

C:\Users\mona\playing-for-data\renderdoc\x64\Debug>
```

Here's the result of renderdoc.dll (which is in the same folder as renderdocui.exe) it says one of the libraries is blacklisted. I am not sure if that's the cause of problem but I know renderdocui.exe needs renderdoc.dll and it could cause it. I wonder how this could be fixed?
[image]

I used the free trial version of .Net Reflector and it says it can't find the renderdoc.dll while this dll is on the same directory as renderdocui.exe 
[image]

I also get all these errors for renderdoc.dll on which renderdocui.exe depends:
[image]

Comment: Maybe set your project target to x86 instead of x64. I expect that dll to be 32 bits and your 64bits exe will not load that dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying dependency walker on the renderdoc.dll is the right approach. Among all the missing libraries there is the IlmImf.dll. This library belongs to OpenEXR, one of your project dependencies. You need to make sure that either this library is in your working directory or its enclosing directory is listed in your PATH environment variable. Neither seems to be the case here.
The other missing libraries should cause no problems.